# Efeitos em conjunto com scroll suave

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Gostaria de colocar outros efeitos na sequência do *scroll*. Abaixo segue o código que estou utilizando e que apenas faz o *scroll*. Como posso utiizar mais efeitos dentro desse código. *Bounce* por exemplo.

```
var $doc = $('html, body');
$('.scrollSuvave').click(function() {
    $doc.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 1200);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Aconselho a não implementar isso, navegadores possuem addons ou flags nativas para simular isso já.

Comment: Diego. Você se refere a colocar mais efeitos além do scroll? Deixar apenas o scroll?

Comment: Você quer adicionar rolagem suave ao rolamento do mouse?, ou você quer que um scroll suave para mostrar um item fora da tela?

Comment: Já tenho um scroll suave. Quero acrescentar outro efeito ao chegar no final do scroll. Quando se clica no link o scroll começa e ao chegar na seção quero que tenha um efeito. Bounce por exemplo. Fazendo com que a seção tenha esse efeito na sequência do scroll. Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score 0):

Consulte os tipos easing para alterar a forma que o animate se corporta. 
https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

```
var easing = "easeOutBounce";
$doc.animate({
     scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 1200, easing);
return false;
```

*Lembrando que é necessário importar o jquery-ui junto.*

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

O arquivo você baixa em https://jqueryui.com/download/all/

**Outras opções**

Para realizar outra animação após o término você pode adicionar logo depois da primeira, que eles serão colocados em uma fila pelo jquery, e quando uma terminar a próxima animação será executada.

```
$doc.animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 1200).animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 1200);
```

,ou utilizar a opção do oncomplete do animate

```
var oncomplete = function(){
     //código que será executado após o término da animação de scroll
}

$doc.animate({
   scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 1200, easing, oncomplete);
return false;
```

, ou usar um Timeout com o tempo do scroll

```
setTimeout(oncomplete,1200);
```

Comment: Por gentileza. Poderia escrever o exemplo do "Lembrando que é necessário importar o jquery-ui junto." Pois devo ter feito algo errado. Coloquei esse código no arquivo JS var easing = "easeOutBounce";
$doc.animate({
     scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 1200, easing);
return false;      conforme orientou. como não rodou devo ter feito ou deixado de fazer algo. rsrs

Comment: Para adicionar o jquery-ui basta adicionar <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script> no cabeçalho logo após da importação do jquery. E o CSS também <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">

Comment: Tá de rosca. rs. Fiz na Head  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css"> Antes do</body> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> e no arquivo main.js temos: var easing = "easeInBounce";
$doc.animate({
     scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 1200, easing);
return false;

  P fav onde errei. Ob.

Comment: consegui implementar com o plugin jquery easing.Valeu obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o plugin [jQuery Easing Plugin (version 1.3)](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) (incluso no exemplo abaixo) que possui uma lista de efeitos. Abaixo eu usei o **easeInBounce**:

```js
var $doc = $('html, body');
$('.scrollSuvave').click(function() {
    $doc.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 1200, "easeInBounce");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
 * jQuery Easing v1.3 - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
 *
 * Uses the built in easing capabilities added In jQuery 1.1
 * to offer multiple easing options
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - jQuery Easing
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD License. 
 * 
 * Copyright Â© 2008 George McGinley Smith
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of 
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list 
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials 
 * provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse 
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 *  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 *  GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED 
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 *  NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED 
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
 *
*/

// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
 def: 'easeOutQuad',
 swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
  return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
 },
 easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
 },
 easeInQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
 },
 easeOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
 },
 easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
 },
 easeInOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeInExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
 },
 easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if (t==0) return b;
  if (t==d) return b+c;
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
  return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
 },
 easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
 },
 easeInOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
  return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
 },
 easeOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
 },
 easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
  if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
  if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
  else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
  if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
  return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
 },
 easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
  return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
 },
 easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
  return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
 },
 easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158; 
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
 },
 easeInBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
 },
 easeOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
  } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
  } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
  } else {
   return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
  }
 },
 easeInOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if (t < d/2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce (x, t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
  return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
 }
});

/*
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - EASING EQUATIONS
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD License. 
 * 
 * Copyright Â© 2001 Robert Penner
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of 
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list 
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials 
 * provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse 
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 *  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 *  GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED 
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 *  NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED 
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
 *
 */
</script>
<a href="#teste" class="scrollSuvave">
   Clique-me
</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="teste">
   Olá!
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar o posicionamento no evento de scroll e chamar a sua animação dependendo do posicionamento:

```
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
     var windowOffsetTop
     var triggered = false
     //  verifica se é crhome ou firefox para ver onde está a posição da 
     //   window
     if (!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore) {
         windowOffsetTop = e.path[1].pageYOffset
     } else if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
         windowOffsetTop = e.pageY
     } 

     // verifica posicionamento da window e se a função já foi disparada         
     if (windowOffsetTop >= 300 && !triggered) {
        triggered = true
         // chame a sua animacao aqui
        console.log("animation")
     }
  })
```